# Set collectionviewcell size equal to content

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

i've created a collectionViewCell, which contain a imageView and a label. The label is however set to sizeToFit, so it will resize according to content. The issue is i cant seem to set the collectionVieCell size to the size of the content inside the cell. here is my code below:

[image]

**Custom Cell**

```
class BrowseCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var mainImageView:UIImageView?
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel:UILabel?


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: CGRect())



        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        titleLabel?.sizeToFit()


        self.contentView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth







    }
    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

**collectionView delegate methods**

```
    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("ItemCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! BrowseCell






        cell.titleLabel?.text = testText




        return cell
    }

    // MARK: WaterfallLayoutDelegate

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {




        return CGSizeMake(140, 150)
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {
        var reusableView: UICollectionReusableView? = nil



        return reusableView!
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify cell size after being loaded, You can try to do a methodology like the one used below.

You can try to get the cell at index path & get label width.

You can also put all text you want to load in array & set width according to number of characters.

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {

 let flickrPhoto =  photoForIndexPath(indexPath)
      //2
      if var size = flickrPhoto.thumbnail?.size {
        size.width += 10
        size.height += 10
        return size
       }
      return CGSize(width: 100, height: 100)
  }
```